# CSS set parameters of item that has lost attention

Tags: c++, css, qt

I have an item that I am trying to edit with CSS:

```
QTreeView#databaseView:item:selected
{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

When the item is selected the font turns white.

The problem I am having is that if I click on another window/program, the item loses attention in the window and the text turns black. I would like it to stay white.

*Is there a way in CSS to check if the attention has been lost so I can make it white?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. A code sample would be helpful. 

It sounds like you want to click something and have the color of the text turn to white and then stay white even when toher things are clicked on, kind of like how a checkbox works. Is that correct?

Comment: This is correct. I would like it to stay while while selected, even if the program loses attention. It seems like there might be some backend default CSS happening to make it black when the window loses focus.

Comment: Do you have a code sample? I've never seen the item and selected psudo-selectors that you are using before and without seeing the code it makes it harder to fix. Additionally, do you have access to the javascript or the html? This is pretty simple JS and can be hacked together in HTML using checkboxes.

Comment: I am not sure what code example to provide? I have a QTreeView that contains items (its like a table of select-able items). Selected Items have white text. Unselected have another color. My issue is that I have a selected Item, but when the program loses attention, the font then switches to black. Is there somthing like ":lose-attention" "lost-focus" param I can use? Something like this must exist to be turning it black. I only have access to CSS, this is using Qt in C++.

Comment: Not that I know of. Here's a list of all the psudo classes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes so I would take a look through there to see if any will work, but a lot of them down't have across the board support.